# Login using jQuery mobile and php

Tags: php, jquery-mobile, authentication

I have this code for login on jQuery mobile. But, it does not work and nothing happens .. when I submit I return to the same page.

Like if he does not enter the php file.

Here is the ajax script:

```
   <script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#loginform").submit( function(){
    $.post('LoginExcution.php',
    $(this).serialize(), function(data){ $("#errorm").html(data)}};
    return false;
    }); 
</script>
```

and here is html:

```
<div data-role="page" id="login">
    <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
</div>
<div data-role="content" style="padding: 15px">
    <div style="text-align:center">
        <img style="width: 50%; height: 50%" src="logo.jpg" />
    </div>
    <form id="loginform" method='post'>
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                        <label for="textinput2" style="text-align:right">
                           Email:
                        </label>
                        <input id="textinput2" name="login" value="" type="text"/>
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                        <label for="textinput3" style="text-align:right">
                            Password:                            </label>
                        <input id="textinput3" name="password" value="" type="password"/>
                    </fieldset>
                </div>     
                <h3 id="errorm"> <?php if (isset($_GET['msg'])){ 

          echo "Invalid username or password";    
 } 


 ?></h3>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" data-inline="true" data-  icon="arrow-l" data-iconpos="left" value="login"/>
            </form>
```

and here LoginExcution.php:

```
                    //Sanitize the POST values
$login = $_POST['login'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

         $aqry="SELECT * FROM admin WHERE name='$login' AND password='".$_POST['password']."'";

           $employeeresult=mysql_query($eqry);  
            $adminresult=mysql_query($aqry);
    if( $employeeresult || $adminresult ){
     //Check whether the query was successful or not



                  if(mysql_num_rows($adminresult) == 1) {
        //Login Successful

        $member = mysql_fetch_assoc($adminresult);
        $_SESSION['MEMBER_ID'] = $member['AdID'];
        $_SESSION['NAME'] = $member['name'];


        header("location: mlogin.php");
        exit();
        }  
                            else { 
             //Login failed 
         header("Location: mobile/mlogin.php?msg=invalid%20name%20or%20password"); 
              exit(); 
             }
```

Thank you

Comment: You can't redirect user's browser using AJAX response. Do it using Javascript

Comment: I searched google and most pepole do it this way @AlexanderLarikov

Comment: and it doesn't work, right? :)

Comment: Then how I do it with javascript? :)

Comment: In your `LoginExcution.php` in response you can print URL to which you want redirect user, and in `$.post` callback you can redirect user like this `window.location` = data;`

Comment: You're storing passwords plain in your database?

Answer (score 2):

your script is messed up, try it with this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#loginform").submit(function() {
    $.post('LoginExcution.php', $(this).serialize(), function(data) { 
      $("#errorm").html(data); // semicolon missing in your code
    }); // round bracket and semicolon missing in your code
  }); // round bracket missing in your code
  return false;
});
```

additionally, I personally would prefer a JSON-encoded result like

`{ status: 'error', msg: 'some message text' }`

or

`{ status: 'ok', msg: 'logging in...' }`.

You could then decide whether to display an error message or redirect to another page via "location.href = ..." by switching the received status.